# submit a parameter with PrimeFaces onClick?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, parameters, dialog

I have this Table:

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 50%;
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 50%;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
  <ui:repeat var="customerInList" value="#{customerListController.resultMap.currentPositionResultList}">                                           <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">#{customerInList.lastName} #{customerInList.firstName}</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">#{customerInList.postalStreet}
        <p:commandButton id="editCustomerButton" label="+" iconPos="center" onclick="PF('editCustomerDialog').show()"/>
        <br/>#{customerInList.postalCode}  #{customerInList.postalCity}
        <br/>#{customerInList.phoneNumber}
        <br/>#{customerInList.email}
                                
      </div>
    </div>
  </ui:repeat>
</div>
</div>
  <p:dialog widgetVar="editCustomerDialog">
                    
  </p:dialog>
```

And this Method

```
public void parseParameter(int ID){
   this.ID = ID;
}
```

so here comes my problem. 
As you can maybe already see I am trying to create a Popup to show more details about the customer. My Idea was that I could parse the Id of the customer from an Invisible div or something like this so I can get the remaining data from my database with this ID but that did not work for me.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: What tutorial are you using? And off-topic: Why don't you use a table? Because someone told you they are 'bad'? You use divs and then tell them to behave like table header/row/cells. That is in my (not so) humble opinion even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `f:setPropertyActionListener` to set values  to your bean from your `p:commandButton` then use the `action` event of your button to get any extra data from your DB and you can show your dialog on the `oncomplete` event instead of `onclick` so it get execute after your bean method.

```
<p:commandButton id="editCustomerButton" label="+" iconPos="center" action="#{customerListController.methodToGetYourRemainingData}" oncomplete="PF('editCustomerDialog').show()">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{customerListController.ID}" value="#{customerInList.ID}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this.